# Polymer js application deployment

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have create a polymer js application And I can run this application in localhost by "gulp serve", but How can I deploy this application in live server

Any suggestion will be thankful for me

Answer (score 2):

Depends.

Did you use the [Polymer Starter Kit](https://github.com/polymerelements/polymer-starter-kit/releases)?

If yes, just run `gulp` and everything should be neatly saved in a `dist` directory. Then you just upload the contents of your dist directory on your server.

If you don't use Polymer Starter Kit, the process still applies. You don't need any compilation to deploy Polymer applications. Just make sure everything is loaded correctly.

Comment: Yes I use starter kit. Main problem is in the routing. I use for routing page.js. Everything going fine but when I click on any link the page redirect to the routing page but when I refresh that page then the page goes to the root dierctory. Can't find any solution for this :(

Comment: Are you using the hashbang? In your `routing.html` you should set `hashbang: true`, because only than a refresh stays at the same URI.

Comment: Glad it helped. You may mark the answer as answered, so I can get these delicious imaginary points :)

Comment: If that doesnt work try this:  if (window.location.port === '') {  // if production
    // Uncomment app.baseURL below and
    // set app.baseURL to '/your-pathname/' if running from folder in production
    app.baseUrl = '/YOURURL/'; // website.com/YOURURL
  }